# Construct specific instance of ObjectWriter from the shared ObjectMapper in Jackson 2 to ignore null fields

Tags: java, data-binding, cxf, jackson, fasterxml

I am working with Jackson 2 and CXF.

I have done lots of research to find a clean and safe way to get a writer object from the shared object mapper that is given to CXF for un/marshaling JSON.  I cannot just use annotation or set the mapper object to ignore null fields when serializing  due to some business logic.

The code below seem to be very correct, but the output JSON still include null fields.  Please help !!

```
ObjectWriter  writer = this.jacksonMapper.writer().without(  SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES ) ;            
if( writer.isEnabled( SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES  ) )      {
   System.out.println("Oppa gangname style");
}
String json = null;
try {
   json = writer.writeValueAsString( myObject );
   System.out.println ( json ) ;
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException() ;
}
```

The if case verify that I have successful disable SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES.
However, the result is still include null fields.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an older Jackson version but this works for me:

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
return mapper.writeValueAsString(input);
```

The docs say `SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES` only applies to generating JSON strings from `Map` objects.

Comment: from Map objects...ohhh, I totally ignored that part.  However, I need to refer to the shared mapper object that read annotations...humn, I wish there is a util method to clone the shared object mapper then I can configure that clone :D.   Thanks alot